# 長期記憶性のある時系列データの解析に関する質問

Tags: python, r

現在、表題のようなデータに対して分析を実行しています。

データの内容に関しては規約があるため詳しく説明することができませんが、以下のような方法で採取されたデータです。ここで、被説明変数をy,説明変数をｘとします。また、時刻をｔとします。

時刻ｔにy(t)が観測される。直近の説明変数x(T|t-100<T<t),(直近100イベントのレコードｘ)が収集される。また、説明変数ｘは長期記憶性を持つことが知られている(時刻間で強い相関を持つ)。また、イベント発生時刻ｔは通常の時系列解析で想定されるような連続値を取らないです。具体的には、ポアソン点過程に従う非連続なイベントです。

上記のようなデータであるため、ARIMA modelのような通常の時系列解析には乗らない解析となります。また、OLS推定しようとすると、変数間に強烈な相関があるため、多重共線性が問題となり正しいパラメータの推定を行うことができません。

この分析のゴールは、説明変数のパラメータ正しい推定です(予測ではなく識別問題です)。もし、なにかアイディアがある方がいらっしゃれば、教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 専門家ではないので間違ったコメントをしていたら申し訳ないのですが・・・多重共線性が発生する場合、不要な説明変数を減らすのが第一選択になると思います。説明から察するに、x(t-1) -> x(t) -> y(t)という因果関係になっているわけですから、説明変数をx(t)のみに絞ってはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 時系列モデルだと多重共線性という言葉はあまり使わないと思います「自己相関」とか「単位根」という言葉はご存知でしょうか?

Comment: 用語の意味がどうも食い違っているようなので, いくつか確認させてください. まず, `x(t)` がポアソン点過程とのことですが, ポアソン点過程は無記憶な過程の典型例です. (あるいは「非一様ポアソン過程」のことかもしれませんが, 一旦理論モデルの話は脇において) そちらの言う 「`x(t)` が長期記憶」というのは, `x[t]` がほとんどの時点でゼロなので `y(t) = b0 * x[t] + b1 * x[t-1] + b100 * x[t-100]` のような回帰モデルを当てはめようとしたところ, `x[t], ..., x[t-100]` 間で多重共線性がある (実際にはゼロが多すぎるからかも?) のでうまく推定できてないように見える, ということでしょうか?

Comment: その上で「説明変数のパラメータの正しい推定」というのは, 上記のような100時点への回帰モデルが正しいという信念があって正しいパラメータを推定したい, ということでしょうか? それとも何か別の形で y と x の関係をうまく表現できる式でもいいので見つけたい, ということでしょうか? これら2点にお答えいただければ, もう少し役に立ちそうな回答ができると思います.

Answer (score 0):

基本的な時系列解析(Arima,var等のモデル)は、全て知っています。このデータは、通常の連続時系列データとは異なり、離散サンプリングが行われているデータになります。(観測時系列の感覚が等間隔ではないという意味です)。その点で通常の時系列解析には乗らない解析になります。イメージとしては、非定常点過程における時間変更定理が適応される前の非常に汚いデータをイメージしていただくのが分かりやすいかと思います。

Comment: 質問の追加情報であるなら、質問本文に追記するようにしてください。